# Will there be a drag for a solid body already dragged due to reaction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

By learning Fluid Structure Interaction tutorials, I managged to simulate a 2d transient fsi simulation using Comsol fsi fully coupled module. A solid body due to motion in vertical direction experience reaction force in horizontal direction. This horizontal force moves the body. I managed to simulate till this. My doubt is due to this resultant motion will the solid body experience drag? I hv this doubt because, it is due to drag experienced the body moves horizontally. Will there be another drag for a dragged body?

Comment: When a body in a fluid is driven by a force in a horizontal direction but experiences motion in the vertical direction, that is called _lift_.  As for what is happening in your simulation, you will have to provide more details.

Comment: Just to echo what @John1024 said -- it's very unclear what your simulation is and what phenomenon occurred and what you are confused about. What shape is the body? Is it rotating? What is causing the vertical motion (gravity, motion, etc)? There needs to be a lot more details given and ideally some schematics of the setup and some plots of results to help you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Here are the details: my body is 2d ellipse. It is prescribed with only vertical sinusoidal motion but free to move horizontal direction in case any force exist. It is proven that a vertical motion inside a fluid generates a horizontal reaction force. That generated horizontal force moves the body. During such generated motion, will there be any drag to be included again?

Comment: That helps a little bit but you still haven't provided essential information like (a) the orientation of the cylinder or (b) the Reynolds number.  If the cylinder is oriented off-axis, then it is natural that it will generate lift.  It is also possible for vortex shedding to cause horizontal motion.  Without the details, all we can do is guess.  If you want helpful answers, provide plots, schematics, dimensions, etc.

Comment: @john1024: it's a 2d ellipse.  X axis,  horizontal is along the length of the ellipse and y axis, vertical axis is along the width of the ellipse.I m not intrested what causes the horizontal motion instead want to know for this prescribed lift that produces drag horizontally,  will there be resistive force again? We have provided action of vertical motion and there is horizontal reaction, will there be a additional drag for this horizontal motion?

Comment: Since, in your case, it is the vertical motion that is forced, it is the horizontal force that is called `lift`.  _"will there be a additional drag for this horizontal motion?"_  _Additional_ relative to what?

Comment: @john1024: because of the drag (or lift as you call) the body is moving horizontally. Any body moving in fluid will experience resistance force. for this motion too will there besuch a resitance force or drag?

Comment: any luck @John1024

Answer (score 0):

I learnt now this is what called induced drag. more information are here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag